# Is it Possible by having Attribute Value "title" getting the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1).
Iam trying to get parent class of  "Multiple option selected"
Iam not sure where is the mistake in below code., as there are many classes of

> - Error :  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>
> **> [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/kqd93ott/)**

**HTML :**

```
<div class="search_grouped">
   <select size="5" class="attrSelect" multiple="multiple">

        <option value="navid=12100138+4288199998+4288234155+4294957236" name="3m" title="3M (39)">
            3M (39)
        </option>

        <option value="navid=12100138+4288199998+4288234155+4294904280" name="superior abrasives" title="Superior Abrasives (20)">
            Superior Abrasives (20)
        </option>

        <option value="navid=12100138+4288199998+4288234155+4294940736" name="tru-maxx" title="Tru-Maxx (40)">
            Tru-Maxx (40)
        </option>

    </select>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$('.attrSelect').change(function(e) {
    var refineOptionTitleP  = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('title').parent('.search_grouped').css('border','10px solid green');

});
```

**OR**

2).Is is possible to get the parent element by NODENAME

```
var eventNode = e.target.nodeName;
  $(eventNode).parent();
```

Appreciate your help. 
Thanks!

Comment: what is the element's title for which you for finding parent?

Comment: Thanks Mike, "option title" will not be static, it will be changing as per the product, so iam trying to use $(this).

Comment: You are trying to access parent of an Attr "Title". Why is that? What is it that you want to select? "option" element or "select" element?

Comment: anything will be static? on which you can trust?

Comment: @Comet I want to select "div" element, i cannot use class name to select the div, because there are many div's with same class :-(

Comment: You can only access parent of a html element not attribute. try $(this).parent('.search_grouped')

Comment: @Mike, Nope. complete dom is loading dynamicaly.

Comment: Why with title? You only really need to do this http://jsfiddle.net/kqd93ott/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can only access parent of a html element not attribute. 
Try `$(this).parent('.search_grouped')`

It will select the parent div of selected option. See fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/kqd93ott/1/